# Storing a multidimensional array as an object variable, adding additional keys to the array

Tags: php, oop, object, multidimensional-array

So I have a multidimensional array which is stored in an object. I want to add additional keys to this array.

**Here's what I have:**

```
$object->pathsArray = array(
    "key1" => array('path' => '/some/path/to/some/file.php', 'action' => 'index'),
    "key2" => array('path' => '/some/path/to/some/class.php', 'action' => 'method2')
);
```

**And here's what I assumed would work but did not:**

```
$object->pathsArray['key3'] = array('path' => '/some/path/to/some/method/or/script.php', 'action' => 'method3');
```

**My first workaround:**

```
$newPathsArray = array("key3" => array('path' => '/some/path/to/some/method/or/script.php', 'action' => 'method3'));   
$object->pathsArray = array_merge($object->pathsArray, $newPathsArray);
```

**Another workaround that SHOULD work:**

```
$tempPathsArray = $object->pathsArray;
$tempPathsArray['key3'] = array('path' => '/some/path/to/some/method/or/script.php', 'action' => 'method3');
$object->pathsArray = $tempPathsArray;
```

**So my question:** Is there a simpler syntax (ie: one line solution) or am I forced to bring in a temp. variable, append to that then merge/re-assign the value to the object?

Comment: When you say the first version did not work, in what way did it fail? Did the `pathsArray` simply not change? If that's the case, it suggests that the object has some kind of custom get/set logic that is giving you a *copy* of the actual stored array each time you request it (and thus the only way to actually change it is to use the set logic, overwriting the whole array). If that's the case, then your first workaround is probably the simplest way available.

Comment: @Tom how did you set the `key1` and `key2` keys initially? Is the `pathsArray` attribute defined as private/protected?

Comment: @Amber, I didn't even consider the get/set logic which now explained makes perfect sense.

Comment: @Sandeepan, since I was using get/set logic, it was defined as private. Simply adding: public $pathsArray; fixed the problem, I can now use the one line solution.

Comment: @Tom great.. but I am not sure how you were able to set `pathsArray` directly in your workarounds but not able to set `pathsArray['key3']`

Comment: @Tom, please write an answer to this question, stating how you solved your own problem. Then accept that answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to write an answer, but I'm not able to comment.
I think that it's not correct to make an attribute public just to use it by that way. The correct thing should be make a setter to fill it, not modifying the class design just for that.